# Socket.close stuck for 15 minutes

Tags: java, sockets, sslsocketfactory

I've developed my own MMORPG game client and server using SSLSockets.  New connections get a dataoutput/input stream in their own threads.  In my main thread loop, I have a method that goes through the connection map and closes connections (inactivity kicks, requested logouts, etc.).

My game server randomly hangs for 15 minutes so every 60 seconds, in another thread, I print out a stacktrace and how many loops the main thread has run.

```
main: [sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method),
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175),
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836),
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870),
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199),
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209),
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285),
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863),
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:735),
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.sendAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2087),
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.warning(SSLSocketImpl.java:1914),
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.closeInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1677),
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:1615),
com.jayavon.game.server.MyServer.processClientConnectionMapV2(MyServer.java:6427),
com.jayavon.game.server.MyServer.main(MyServer.java:708)]
```

From this I can tell that my server gets stuck when trying to close connections:

```
clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getSocket().close();
```

Here is the condensed method it is getting stuck running (which hangs the whole server):

```
private void processClientConnectionMapV2(boolean disconnectAll) {
    try {
        Iterator<Entry<String, ClientConnectionV2>> it = MyServer.ClientConnectionMapV2.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, ClientConnectionV2> clientConnectionEntry = it.next();
            
            if (clientConnectionEntry.getValue().isToDisconnect()
                    || disconnectAll){ //this connection should be disconnected
                if (!hasOutstandingBacklogMessagesV2(MyServer.ClientConnectionMapV2.get(clientConnectionEntry.getKey()))
                        || clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getDisconnectLoopsSkipped() > 4
                        || disconnectAll) {
                    MyServer.LOGGER.warn("----REMOVE CONNECTION----<processClientConnectionMapV2>----    " + clientConnectionEntry);
                    
                    //close the actual connection here
                    try {
                        clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getSocket().close();
                        clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getDataInputStream().close();
                        clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getDataOutputStream().close();
                        clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getCommandHandlerV2().loggedOut = true;
                        serverConnectionNumber--;
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        LOGGER.warn("unable to close in Server processClientConnectionsV2", e1);
                        LOGGER.warn("connection was already closed on client side");
                    }

                    //remove from iterator and ClientConnectionMapV2
                    it.remove();
                } else {
                    clientConnectionEntry.getValue().setDisconnectLoopsSkipped(clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getDisconnectLoopsSkipped() + 1);
                    MyServer.LOGGER.warn("----SKIP REMOVE CONNECTION----<processClientConnectionMapV2>----    " + clientConnectionEntry);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.fatal("MAIN LOOP: processClientConnectionsV2: ", e);
    }
}
```

I've rewritten my connection code so much recently to try to fix the hangs and I have finally found the root cause - but I'm unsure how to address it.

Comment: _"I have finally found the root cause"_ - it might help if you shared that

Comment: I did - the socket.close is where it hangs - I also shared the stacktrace.

Comment: The root cause is that you are closing the socket while another thread is reading or writing from/to it, and that thread can be blocked on the socket I/O itself. Instead of this idler-loop thread you should just use a read timeout on the socket, and close it when you get `SocketTimeoutException` on reading, in the thread that is handling that client.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne thank you.  I was looking at setSoTimeout, but it seems to only help with read and not write.  Any ideas there?  Also have no idea how long to set it for.  I readUTF and writeUTF strings back and forth so only text data.

Comment: Set it for the same timeout your present 'inactivity kicks' uses. Nothing can help you with threads being stuck in write except the peer catching up on his reading.

Comment: Interesting. Okay, but I can also kick people adhoc.  Guess I'll have to figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may find this here is how I solved it.  I was unable to just rely on the setSoTimeout method as I wanted the ability to kick players ad hoc.

```
Thread closerThread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        //close the actual connection here
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("closerThread-" + clientConnectionEntry.getKey() + "-" + tmpAccountName + "|" + tmpCharacterName);
            clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getCommandHandlerV2().outgoingMessageBacklog.clear();
            clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getCommandHandlerV2().loggedOut = true;
            serverConnectionNumber--;
            clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getSocket().close();
            clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getDataInputStream().close();
            clientConnectionEntry.getValue().getDataOutputStream().close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            LOGGER.warn("unable to close in Server processClientConnectionsV2", e1);
        }
    }
};
closerThread.start();
```

Comment: Closing the streams when you've already closed the socket is pointless, and closing them beforehand is redundant.